# WordPress Mystique theme is not getting displayed with IE and Lower Versions of FF and Chrome

Tags: wordpress, cross-browser, wordpress-theming

I have installed Wordpress and activated Mystique theme.I simply love the design and functionality provided by the Mystique team.

But the problem is when I try to view my site with IE or any of the little older versions of Firefox or Chrome the page is not getting displayed properly.My Site URL is :
http://blog.subhendu.info/index.php

Any help with this please.

Thanks,

Subhen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Analytics script is inserted before the Doctype at the beginning of the HTML code of your page: it should be inserted just before the closing tag  at the end of the HTML code.

You are copy-pasting directly from an MS Office software in your posts and the resulting code is thus terrible, like:

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left: .75in; text-indent: -.25in; mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1; tab-stops: list .75in; mso-layout-grid-align: none; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: Arial; mso-fareast-font-family: Arial;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">d.</span><span style="font: 7.0pt &amp;amp;amp;"> </span></span>
```

The above code for displaying **2** characters, ouch
While copy-pasting into a new post, you should use (activate Advanced Options first) the icon with a W : Pasting from Word. This should get rid of most of the *particularities* of MS Office.

---

What are the display problems you encountered? Did you compare the demo to your existing homepage?

Browser compatibility: page not centered in IE7 (OK in IE6), small glitch on the active Home tab in IE6 and IE7 and that's all. Fine on Fx 3.0 and Fx 3.6.6
The glitch on the Home tab is already present on the [demo of the theme](http://wp.digitalnature.eu/mystique/)
CSS3 properties like text-shadow, border-radius, box-shadow, etc won't work on old browsers that didn't support it at the time but that's not a real problem as long as your page is stil viewable and functional: these are graceful degradations.

Please begin by (re)moving the GA script